# How to share global state between ViewModel in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, solid-principles

My app is setup as follows:

- GetIt for DI of services
- ViewModels (extends ChangeNotfier)
- Stateless pages with a ChangeNotfierProvider listening to the ViewModel per page

What is the best approach for sharing state between ViewModels to be consumed across pages? Right now I have a central service which is injected into each view model which holds some global state - my gut is saying have the central service expose a stream and have each ViewModel subscribe to that upon initialisation, but not sure if that is the best approach?

Comment: I'd say use the provider package for that as well. Declare a provider for the global state at the root of your widget tree (i.e. above the `MaterialApp`). That way, every widget in your entire app will have access to it. You could also use GetIt for this as well, or BLoC, or singletons, or GetX, or...

Comment: Thanks - maybe I'm being a purist here, but passing state through the widget tree just feels wrong

Comment: It's just another form of dependency injection. Plenty of other frameworks have a DI solution that passes through the widget tree. You also say you are currently using `ChangeNotifierProvider` already, so you are already passing state through the widget tree, just to a much lesser degree.

Comment: That's fair - thanks!